# Wordpress Login takes lots of time in first time . how can i fix it?

Tags: wordpress

Friends i am optimizing a wordpress site. it redirect to the wordpress login but it is taking lots of time to login in first time (approx 30-45 second). Can anyone help me with this. Is there any way by which i can login in less than 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I would do most of my troubleshooting in the [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin along with the [Debug Bar extender](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-extender/) plugin.

This plugin gives you detailed access to everything that is going on behind the scenes. It can also detail memory usage and execution time for each function and database query along with where it was called from.

I would start by doing some checking with the tool then come back here if you get stuck on anything